# VS code terminal exits with this pop up, "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" terminated with exit code: 3221225781."

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-code

I have looked on the internet, and some people suggested updating my windows 11 to the latest build; however, it did not solve the problem. One person indicated that they could solve the issue by reinstalling the windows. I can't afford to perform a clean install. How can I solve this issue? I can't open PowerShell or terminal natively aside from vs-code. As soon as I try running windows Powershell this error shows up.
[image: Windows PowerShell Error.]
[[image: VS-Code Error.2]

Comment: Check if `C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\` is in your PATH environment variable

Comment: @Theo It is not exactly the same but there is something similar in the PATH environment variable, "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\".

Comment: Missing `mscoree.dll` is *Microsoft .NET Runtime Execution Engine* (`C:\Windows\System32\mscoree.dll`). Install (or reinstall) the *Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package*.

Comment: @JosefZ Installed and reinstalled, however, did not work.

Comment: Your PATH seems OK then. You could try installing the optional [2022-05 Cumulative Update for Windows 11 for x64-based Systems (KB5014019)](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5014019), but there are [issues](https://www.windowslatest.com/2022/05/28/watch-out-for-new-issues-in-windows-11-kb5014019-update/) with that as well I'm afraid..

Comment: @Theo, I have already installed this update to solve my issue but in vain.

Comment: Bummer.. Then perhaps try the [system file checker tools](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-system-file-checker-in-windows-365e0031-36b1-6031-f804-8fd86e0ef4ca)

Comment: I don't know what happened but it started working automatically yesterday. Maybe it has to do with the recent update.